# How to enable WebGL in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: drivers, browser, opengl, plugin

I want to try out WebGL as I'm learning OpenGL currently and, well yeah, kind of interested in how WebGL looks like.

I tried some demo sites like [this](http://aleksandarrodic.com/p/daily-routines/) or [that](http://apps.playcanvas.com/will/ammo/vehicle). But unfortunately they don't work. I get the warning both in firefox and chromium:

> This page requires a browser that supports WebGL.

Browsing to the official WebGL [homepage](http://get.webgl.org/) tells me the following:

> Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card.

I've found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/299346/94697) answer on AskUbuntu, but enabling the software rendering list override does not enable WebGL for me in chromium.

I'm running [Sabayon](http://www.sabayon.org/) Linux x86_64 with an NVIDIA GPU:

```
 ~ # uname -a
Linux qdoe 3.9.0-sabayon #1 SMP Thu Jun 27 07:53:45 UTC 2013 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
~ # lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 640] (rev a1)
 ~ # firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 20.0.1
 ~ # chromium --version
Chromium 27.0.1453.110
```

Using following drivers:

```
 ~ # equo search x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers-319.32#3.9.0-sabayon
>> @@ Package: x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers-319.32#3.9.0-sabayon branch: 5, [sabayon-limbo] 
>>   Available:     version: 319.32 ~ tag: 3.9.0-sabayon ~ revision: 0
>>   Installed:     version: 319.32 ~ tag: 3.9.0-sabayon ~ revision: 0
>>   Slot:          0,3.9.0-sabayon
>>   Homepage:      http://www.nvidia.com/ 
>>   Description:   NVIDIA GPUs kernel drivers 
>>   License:       NVIDIA-r1
 ~ # lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia               9376114  23
```

Any ideas how to enable WebGL in either Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the WebGL public [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists), both firefox and chrome support WebGL with Nvidia GPUs in X11/Linux.

In my case the wrong graphic driver was selected.

```
 ~ # eselect opengl list
Available OpenGL implementations:
  [1]   nvidia
  [2]   xorg-x11 *
```

Setting it back to nvidia fixed my issues with WebGL.

```
 ~ # eselect opengl set nvidia
Switching to nvidia OpenGL interface... done
```

Comment: do you mean that intel video cards (for firefox) are not supported by webgl?